# Pasar variable de una función a otra

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, gps

siento esta pregunta tonta pero estoy obcecado y no me sale
tengo esta funcion que me devuelve las coordenadas

```
function coordenadas() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
        $('#latitud').val(location.coords.latitude);
        $('#longitud').val(location.coords.longitude);
        var latitude=(location.coords.latitude);
        var longitude=(location.coords.longitude);
        var map;
        var center = {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude};
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: center,
                zoom: 6
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude},
                map:map,
                title: 'Ubicacion'
            });
        }
        initMap();
    });
}
```

y luego tengo esta llamada a ajax que es para que el trabajador cuando firme que se guarde hora y fecha turno nombre, etc de cuando ficho pero ahora me piden tambien la posición en la cual ficho,

```
$('#finicio').on('click', function(e){ // add event submit

    coordenadas()

    var cod=$('#trabajador').val()
    var linea=$('#linea').val()
    var turno=$('#turno').val()
    var fecha=$('#fecha').val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/firmainicio.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            cod:cod,
            linea:linea,
            turno:turno,
            fecha:fecha,
        },
        success: function (response) {
            if (response=="null"){
                $('#myModal1').modal('toggle');
            }
            else{
                $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

pero no me funciona coger la posición de la función coordenadas para poder pasarlas al ajax y guardarlas en la base de datos para luego listarlas
espero puedan ayudarme gracias
Ejecutando $.when que no se si se usa así me sigue devolviendo la variable longitud y latitud vacia

```js
    $('#finicio').on('click', function(e){ // add event submit
        $.when(coordenadas()).then(function () {
                var cod=$('#trabajador').val()
                var linea=$('#linea').val()
                var turno=$('#turno').val()
                var fecha=$('#fecha').val()

                var latitud=$('#latitud').val()
                var longitud=$('#longitud').val()
                console.log(latitud)
                console.log(longitud)

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax/firmainicio.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        cod:cod,
                        linea:linea,
                        turno:turno,
                        fecha:fecha,
                        latitud:latitud,
                        longitud:longitud
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response=="null"){
                            $('#myModal1').modal('toggle');
                        }
                        else{
                            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                        }
                    }
                })
        })
    });
```

Comment: Cuando haces esto en la función coordenadas()  $('#latitud').val(location.coords.latitude);
$('#longitud').val(location.coords.longitude); ¿puedes visualizar las coordenadas?

Comment: Estás utilizando la api de google maps para lo cual necesitas activar el servicio en una cuenta de google y pasar al objeto tu api key

Comment: si, puedo ver las coordenadas, he probado a meter los valores en un input hidden y los mete pero despues de que se ejecute la funcion "coordenadas"

Comment: ¿ @KeTeMeTo has probado a añadir esto después de ejecutar la función coordenadas()? var latitud=$('#latitud').val()
 var longitud=$('#longitud').val() y luego pasarlas junto con los otros datos?

Comment: claro si eso es lo que he probado pero me las envia en blanco, ya que la funcion coordenadas() se llama antes pero termina de ejecutarse despues, ese es el problema que me las envia en blanco porque cuando las envia todavia no las ha rellenado, me funciona ejecutando coordenadas() en el document.ready pero claro hay solo actualiza la posicion cuando se recarga la pagina no al hacer click en firmar como yo quiero... no se si me entiendes. pd:gracias pos contestar!

Comment: ¿@KeTeMeTo Has probado utilizando '$.when()'? serías más o menos así   $.when(coodrenadas()).then(function (response) { ... } donde los puntos suspensivos sería el código que recoge las variables y las manda al servidor

Comment: pues no lo he probado, no sabia que existia esa funcion, voy a probar y te digo

Comment: @ErnestoRM me lo sigue devolviendo vacio si ejecuto coordenadas dentro de la funcion click

Comment: @KeTeMeTo como el siguiente comentario era demasiado largo, te lo he ecrito en forma de respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que [Geolocation.getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) es asincrónico y estás intentando acceder a sus datos de manera sincrónica, por lo cual genera un `racing condition`. No tener este concepto en mente, puede generar varios bugs alrededor de tu app, porque estamos dependiendo de qué tan rápido `getCurrentPosition` resuelve.

Para resolver este tipo de problemas, existe en javascript el concepto de [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). En resumen, esperamos hasta que un proceso se complete para poder continuar con los siguientes procesos.

Para poder usar Promises en coordenadas, deberíamos hacer lo siguiente:

```
function coordenadas() {
  // iniciamos el proceso asincrónico
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      function(location) {
        $('#latitud').val(location.coords.latitude);
        $('#longitud').val(location.coords.longitude);
        var latitude = location.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = location.coords.longitude;
        var map;
        var center = {
          lat: location.coords.latitude,
          lng: location.coords.longitude
        };
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: center,
            zoom: 6
          });
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {
              lat: location.coords.latitude,
              lng: location.coords.longitude
            },
            map: map,
            title: 'Ubicacion'
          });
        }
        initMap();
        // resolvemos devolviendo location, dado por getCurrentPosition
        resolve(location);
      },
      // segundo parámetro de getCurrentPosition es un callback en caso de error
      function error(error) {
        // devolvemos el error
        reject(error);
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Una vez hecho esto, cuando llamamos a coordenadas, podemos esperar hasta tener nuestro resultado:

```
$('#finicio').on('click', function(e) { // add event submit
  coordenadas()
    .then(function success(location) {
      // enviamos al server los datos 
    })
    .catch(function error(error) {
      // mostramos al usuario que hubo un error
    });
})
```

También podemos usar [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), antes no te funcionaba porque este método pide que los argumentos pasados sean [Thenables](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Thenable)

Dependiendo de que versión de javascript es el que soporta tu proyecto, podés usar Asnyc/Await en vez de Promises. Esto es muy conveniente para poder evitar el famoso [Callback Hell](https://blog.hellojs.org/asynchronous-javascript-from-callback-hell-to-async-and-await-9b9ceb63c8e8), que es muy propio de jQuery.

Comment: Esta tarde lo pruebo y te comento, eso es exactamente lo que pasa, el problema es que no sabia solucionarlo

Comment: Funciona perfecto!

Comment: @Yakume pues muchas gracias funciona perfecto y he aprendido como funciona la funcion Promise que no tenia ni idea de que existia

Answer (score 0):

Si ya te funciona la primera función, entonces usa una variable global y lo que debes hacer es declarar una variable al inicio de tu código por ejemplo.

```
 var geo_posicion = [];
```

o si es un string

```
var geo_posicion = "";
```

y luego dentro de la función de coordenadas(); metes el resultado en en esa misma variable por ejemplo

```
 respuesta_coordenadas = window.geo_posicion;
```

> Y de esta forma cuando la necesites usar en otra función solo usas por ejemplo...

```
var locacion = window.geo_posicion;
```

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero no me gustaria tener que usar variables globales para esto

Comment: Y ¿ya intentaste poner los punto y coma al final de cada variable y funcion que tienes arriba? porque por lo que vi todo esto esta sin punto y coma          coordenadas()

    var cod=$('#trabajador').val()
    var linea=$('#linea').val()
    var turno=$('#turno').val()
    var fecha=$('#fecha').val()

Comment: punto y coma en jquery?, es totalmente opcional a no ser que tengas saltos de lineas extraños

Answer (score 0):

¿Y si pruebas a "darle la vuelta"?

Si el problema está en que necesitas el resultado de una función para usarlo en otra, ¿por qué no escribes el código de la segunda dentro de la primera?

quedaría más o menos así:

```
  function coordenadas() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(location) {
        $('#latitud').val(location.coords.latitude);
        $('#longitud').val(location.coords.longitude);
        var latitude=(location.coords.latitude);
        var longitude=(location.coords.longitude);
        var map;
        var center = {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude};
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: center,
                zoom: 6
            });
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: location.coords.latitude, lng: location.coords.longitude},
                map:map,
                title: 'Ubicacion'
            });
        }
        initMap();
    });

        var cod=$('#trabajador').val()
        var linea=$('#linea').val()
        var turno=$('#turno').val()
        var fecha=$('#fecha').val()
        var latitud=$('#latitud').val()
        var longitud=$('#longitud').val()
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/firmainicio.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                cod:cod,
                linea:linea,
                turno:turno,
                fecha:fecha,
                latitud:latitud,
                longitud:longitud
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response=="null"){
                    $('#myModal1').modal('toggle');
                }
                else{
                    $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

                }
            }
        });
    }
}

$('#finicio').on('click', function(e){ // add event submit

    coordenadas()
});
```

Comment: porque las coordenadas las coge en muchas funciones, tengo fichar inicio de jornada, fichar final de jornada, ver posicion actual del trabajador, etc

Comment: Entiendo, es necesario que la función coordenadas() se mantenga separada del otro código..

Comment: exacto, la función coordenadas simplemente tiene que sacar las coordenadas y pintarlas en algún sitio o bien devolverlas, pero poniendo un return tampoco me funciona así que... ni idea