# ¿Como puedo pasar el valor de una varibale en otra en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo el siguiente código:

```
        var traduccion;    
        function respuesta(){
              var original = text;
               const translateParams = {
                text: "Hello World", 
                model_id: 'en-es',
              };

              languageTranslator.translate(translateParams, function (err, translationResult){
                if (err){
                  res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                else{
                  traduccion = translationResult
                }
              });
              }  

    function cambio(){
        respuesta();
        console.log(traduccion);
    }
cambio();
```

El problema es que cuando imprime el resultado de la  funcion `cambio`, me marca un `Undefined`. La variable `traduccion` esta como global pero aún así me lo marca como `undefined`. ¿Cómo podría hacer que en esa función de `cambio` me imprimiera el valor de `traducción`? Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste poner un timeout a la ejecución de cambio()? También podrías asignar algún valor a **traduccion**  inicialmente para ver si imprime su contenido. ¿Has probado desde la consola de tu navegador a realizar el llamado de esta variable?

Comment: `languageTranslator.translate` es asincrona es por eso que `traduccion` no tiene valor al momento de usarla.

Answer (score 0):

Al trabajar de forma asíncrona, se realiza el `console.log()` antes de hacer la asignación de la variable... lo que seria recomendable es realizar el `console.log()` dentro del `else`, después de hacer la asignacion:

```
        var traduccion;    
        function respuesta(){
              var original = text;
               const translateParams = {
                text: "Hello World", 
                model_id: 'en-es',
              };

              languageTranslator.translate(translateParams, function (err, translationResult){
                if (err){
                  res.status(500).json(err);
                }
                else{
                  traduccion = translationResult;
                  // lo llevas aquí
                  console.log(traduccion);
                }
              });
              }  

    function cambio(){
        respuesta();

    }
cambio();
```

Answer (score 0):

Voy a asumir que lo que querés es poder usar la variable traducción en otras partes, en vez de solamente hacer un `console.log`.

En [Pasar variable de una función a otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273167/pasar-variable-de-una-funci%C3%B3n-a-otra/273188#273188) resolvemos un problema muy parecido al tuyo. Para poder obtener el valor de respuesta, hacemos uso de [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

En tu caso, sería algo así:

```
function respuesta() {
  var original = text; // esta variable no se usa
  const translateParams = {
    text: 'Hello World',
    model_id: 'en-es'
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    languageTranslator.translate(translateParams, function(
      err,
      translationResult
    ) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(translationResult);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Y luego en cambio, podemos hacer:

```
function cambio() {
  respuesta()
    .then(function success(r) {
      console.log(r);
    })
    .catch(function error(err) {
      // acá sería mejor manejar el 500
      // así extraémos lógica y respuesta
      // hace sólo una cosa
    });
}

cambio();
```

Dependiendo de tu versión de javascript, podemos escribir cambio con Async/Await:

```
async function cambio() {
  let r;
  try {
    r = await respuesta();
    console.log(r);
  } catch(err) {
    // server 500 error
  }
}

cambio();
```

Comment: Hola Yakume, buenas tardes. Me aparace el siguiente error: `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` a que se debe?

Comment: Ese error es de que algo está escribiendo un header cuando ya se envió una respuesta a cliente. No tiene nada que ver con la pregunta.